# how long can I use reference returned by std::vector::operator[]?

Tags: c++, vector

`std::vector::operator[]` "Returns a reference to the element at position n in the vector container."

Can I use this reference forever? Can I pass it to another thread and use from another thread too? Is it possible that reference is invalidated (cause vector resize, for example) and I have "garbage" instead of real element at some point?

Comment: Any container mutation (except perhaps a `resize` to a smaller value) invalidates vector iterators potentially (though you can compare `capacity()` before and after to guarantee non-invalidation).

Comment: probably there are other cases when reference can be invalidated? can I say that if there are NO mutations (add/delete) than reference guaranteed to be valid?

Comment: according to the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/) `Concurrently accessing or modifying different elements is safe`

Comment: @KerrekSB The vector may have grown and shrunk in the mean time (and thus reallocated, but still have the original size), so a `capacity()` check is not a 100% guarantee.

Comment: @Miklas: Yes. I was assuming silently that you are the only mutator, or perform the check while holding the lock. I guess I should have said "**immediately** before and after".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you pass the entire vector as reference to another thread? it depends.

you can pass a specific reference to an element to another th
read in case that
1) the vector is not destructed before the other thread tries to get that element
2) there is no resizing of the vector after you pass the reference. then the actual pointer of the element may change completly.

EDIT:
I strongly suggest pass the vector as whole with some `std::mutex` as synchronizing lock and continue from there. try to prevent the reference-invalidation at the first place instead of dodging it.

Comment: There are many more cases in which references are invalidated. Erasing the first element in the vector, for instance.

Comment: in other words - resizing. just to be clear, resizing is everything that change the size of the array, not only std::vector::resize, also push_back, emplace_back,erase etc.

Comment: what if I call "reserve", then pass reference, then call push_back. assuming that actual resizing is not required can I hope that reference still will be valid?

Comment: I think that standard speaking it will be safe. in practical point of view - you don't know what kind of optimizations your compiler do soes I wouldn't take the chance.

Answer (score 2):

Almost any mutation to the vector could cause the reference to the element to become invalidated.  If you never mutate the vector then the reference will remain valid.

If you think about a vector as an array then this makes sense as any erasure where you would have to shift elements around could mean you are no longer pointing to the right element and if you ever have to reallocate the memory then the elements will no longer be in the same place as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/) for `operator[]`:

> Concurrently accessing or modifying different elements is safe

If the container shrinks, all the references to removed elements get invalidated (according to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/)). The same applies for any mutation that removes an element.

Data races are well documented for containers in the STL (for C++11, there is no notion of multithreading in C++03 and before).